# Is subtract (-) from cassandra collection creates a tombstone?

Tags: cassandra

After reading about tombstones and collections in cassandra i understand that the right way is to use addition (+) and addition subtraction (-) operators.

All places i have read i got the impression that using this operators instead of overwriting the collection should not create any tombstones.

After doing some tests and reading sstables it seems that when doing the addition, no tombstones are created

But when doing subtraction, i could notice that the sstable gets deletion_info record. this record is different from the record that deletes the whole cell (and not just one entry in a set) so i'm not sure if it's a tombstone or not?

```
6545d91# sstabledump mc-23-big-Data.dbata/cs/customers-49e96fc0011f11e985316d2c86
WARN  11:17:05,402 Only 52.363GiB free across all data volumes. Consider adding more capacity to your cluster or removing obsolete snapshots
[
  {
    "partition" : {
      "key" : [ "da8b9f4e-b063-4254-aee6-acba55b35d83" ],
      "position" : 0
    },
    "rows" : [
      {
        "type" : "row",
        "position" : 143,
        "clustering" : [ "da8b9f4e-b063-4254-aee6-acba55b35d83", "da8b9f4e-b063-4254-aee6-acba55b35d83" ],
        "liveness_info" : { "tstamp" : "2018-12-16T10:47:19.434990Z" },
        "cells" : [
          { "name" : "payments", "deletion_info" : { "marked_deleted" : "2018-12-16T11:00:27.524999Z", "local_delete_time" : "2018-12-16T11:00:27Z" } },
          { "name" : "payments", "path" : [ "da8b9f4e-b063-4254-aee6-acba55b35d81" ], "value" : "", "tstamp" : "2018-12-16T11:15:17.989Z" },
          { "name" : "payments", "path" : [ "da8b9f4e-b063-4254-aee6-acba55b35d82" ], "deletion_info" : { "local_delete_time" : "2018-12-16T11:16:34Z" },
            "tstamp" : "2018-12-16T11:16:34.929999Z"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

Bottom line, my question if this record in a cell is tombstone? 
and if yes, is it possible to avoid it?

```
 { "name" : "payments", "path" : [ "da8b9f4e-b063-4254-aee6-acba55b35d82" ], "deletion_info" : { "local_delete_time" : "2018-12-16T11:16:34Z" },
            "tstamp" : "2018-12-16T11:16:34.929999Z"
  }
```

Comment: That is a tombstone. From what I have read and tested, any manipulation of a set will cause a tombstone generation because "figuring out what changed" is too time consuming. Instead, cassandra will delete and replace the value (that's with inserts and updates, I have not tested + and - operations). The "deletion_info" means it's a tombstone.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to:

```
{ "name" : "payments", "path" : [ "da8b9f4e-b063-4254-aee6-acba55b35d82" ],
  "deletion_info" : { "local_delete_time" : "2018-12-16T11:16:34Z" },
  "tstamp" : "2018-12-16T11:16:34.929999Z"
}
```

Subtraction indeed creates a tombstone to indicate to the storage engine the state of that element (removed) in the collection.  This is so the removal takes precedence over any previous (older timestamped data) additions of that particular element at that path.

In addition, when you provide the entire collection as part of a cql statement, that also creates a tombstone, that's likely what this tombstone represents:

```
{ "name" : "payments", 
  "deletion_info" : { "marked_deleted" : "2018-12-16T11:00:27.524999Z",
  "local_delete_time" : "2018-12-16T11:00:27Z" } 
}
```

Because Cassandra does not employ read-before-write, it simply creates a tombstone for all elements in that column to invalidate all possible existing writes.

If you want to avoid tombstones entirely, consider using [Frozen Collections](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/collection_type_r.html).  With frozen collections, you are required to provide the full collection value every time and all elements of the collection are stored in a single cell.  Because of this there is no need to create a tombstone when updating the collection.

The apparent downside of using frozen collections is that you can't append / remove elements from a collection without first `SELECT`ing the existing contents, and providing a new collection in your `INSERT`/`UPDATE`.  A downside of this is you may have to worry about managing concurrent writes.

Alternatively, if you want to avoid creating tombstones with non-frozen collections, never `INSERT` a full collection (i.e. `INSERT INTO ks.tbl (k, c) VALUES (0, [1,2,3])`.  Instead use appends, i.e `UPDATE ks.tbl SET c = c + [1,2,3] WHERE k = 0`.